# Как узнать, откуда пришел запрос?

Tags: php, сервер, localhost

У меня такой вопрос. Как на `PHP` можно проверить пришел человек на эту страницу с `localhost`-а или нет. Причем `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` использовать нельзя. Также нельзя проводить проверку на `127.0.0.1`. Какие есть еще способы?

Comment: Если человек пришел на вашу страницу с localhost'а, значит этот человек сидит напротив монитора вашего сервера :D

Уточните задачу, что именно вы понимаете под "пришел с localhost'а" и с какой целью вы хотите это проверить?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под localhost'ом?

Comment: Да, я это и имел виду. Надо проверить не посторонний ли человек запускает скрипт на сервере.

Comment: @Elime, на одном ip может сидеть несколько человек. Как их различать?

Comment: @alex_90, по софту? %)

Comment: Можно сделать переходы по реферным ссылкам. Если пользователь вошел без ссылки, значит, он набрал адрес сайта в адресной строке.  
А вам вообще для чего это все?

Comment: Записывать сессию, записывать в сессию время обращения... способов куча! Суть задачи то какова?)

Comment: или вообще, зачем это все надо, поставьте пароль, в качестве защиты и не е*ите себе мозг %)

Comment: @ling, что означает

> переходы по реферным ссылкам

? Чтобы узнать посторонний или нет человек запускает скрипт.

Comment: так и минусов не долго хапануть) UPD// Перепишите вопрос полностью!

Comment: > Надо проверить не посторонний ли человек запускает скрипт на сервере.

Т.е. вы боитесь, что кто-то взломает ваш сервер и подключившись через консоль (или удаленный рабочий стол) начнет локально дергать ваши скрипты?

Это же совершенно бессмысленно. Что бы проверить не было ли постороннего на сервере нужно смотреть логи, ключи авторизации, пароли, исходники и т.п., а не сравнивать ip с localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Чтобы узнать посторонний или нет человек запускает скрипт.

Вариант 1: поставить пароль. Либо сессией, либо httppassw'ом.
Вариант 2 (используется в CMS): инклудом подтягивается файл, где задается переменная. Затем, каждый скрипт CMS'ки проверяет наличие переменной.
Вариант 3: все ссылки на сайт должны содержать какой-то get-запрос (href="site.ru/?partnerId=21534"), значение которого пишется в сессию. Получается вариант 1, только более прозрачный.

Answer (score 1):

Если клиент(браузер) не отправит эту информацию(А многие не отправляют по-умолчанию), узнать ее нельзя. Разве что, с точностью: пришел ли он с вашего сайта или не с вашего.
Если информация отправлена, она лежит в HTTP_REFERRER

Comment: @knes, мне сказали есть способ как-то определить это по `ip`. 

P.S. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать это через `Whois`?

Comment: @knes, а как можно узнать с моего ли сайта пришел он или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Есть две переменные `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` и `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Answer (score 1):

"Надо проверить не посторонний ли человек запускает скрипт на сервере."

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //ip зашедшего на страницу
$your_ip = '182.54.12.482'; //ip с которого можно заходить
if($ip !== $your_ip){
    echo 'Ахтунг! Чужой!';
    exit();
}
```

или я не так понял?

Answer (score 1):

*Вы учли, что если человек просто набрал в адресной строке адрес вашего сайта или его страницы, то такого понятия как `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` просто не будет вообще?*

Сгенерируйте себе куку и проверяйте ее наличие, чужим куку не давайте и будет вам счастье и без паролей

Answer (score 1):

Вот так посылает запрос браузер:

```
GET http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/64726/ivc/95ee?_=1431120826827 HTTP/1.1
Host: ru.stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.2.9999.797 Safari/537.31
Referer: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/64726/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: smth=was-here;
```

Обращаю внимание на заголовок `host`. Да и в самом url адрес есть.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']))
{
  echo 'localhost or http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос актуален для меня.
Ищу способ сделать нечтно вроде этого, но пока вот такой какой-то получается. Не уверен что это даст ожидаемый результат, но близок к нему. Во всяком случае SERVER_NAME даёт нужную информацию о имени сервера, осталось только определить эту информацию о сервере запроса. HTTP_HOST даёт не ту информацию.

```
if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Парсим заголовок запроса
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
if ($name == 'Referer')
    $referer_site = $value;
}

 /**
 * Получаем IP хоста
 * @param str $url
 */
public static function get_host_ip($url) {
    $ip = FALSE;
    if (strpos($url, 'http') !== FALSE) {
        $url_array = parse_url($url); // разбиваем URL на части
        $host = $url_array['host'];
    } else {
        $host = $url;
    }
    $ip = gethostbyname($host); // получаем IP по доменному имени
    if ($ip == $host) { // получили ли мы IP
        $ip = FALSE;
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Дальше уже проверяем как хочется